# How to find handle to a mfc control at mouse point but lie under other control?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, window

I want find control handle lie under other when mouse over, but it only found control above (use `WindowFromPoint`, `ChildWindowFromPoint` , etc does not work).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the controls nested, i.e. there is a parent-child relationship between the controls, or are they just overlapping and unrelated?

Comment: Have a read of [Meandering Through the Maze of MFC Message and Command Routing](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0795/dilascia/dilascia.aspx), it might help you understand where the messages are routed. Or post some code showing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`GetNextWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API call to retrieve next window in Z-Order that lays below this one.

Algorithm could be like this:

1. Get initial window by `HWND hwnd = ChildWindowFromPoint(hwndParent, point);`
2. If `hwnd` is sought-for window then stop
3. `hwnd = GetNextWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);`
4. If `hwnd` contains `point` then go to 2
5. Otherwise go to 3.

Another way - just enumerate all controls on dialog or view, store their rectangles and handles in some container and do the point check manually.